# how to convert escaped c# string with double quotes to escaped javascript string with double quotes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor

I have one problem with using of the strings with escaped symbols, when I am trying to use them in javascript.

At the top of view I initialize variable this way:

```
@{ var lol = "hello \"mister sir\" I am quotes"; }
```

In the javascript I tried different variants. For the test purposes I wrote small function:

```
    $selector = $('#some-button');
    function test(str) {
        $selector.html(str);
        alert(str);
    }
```

There are my attempts:

1. javascript escaping. It works fine either in alert, or in html content.

   ```
   test("hello \"mister sir\" I am quotes");
   ```
2. HtmlAttributeEncode or HtmlEncode. They do not work in all cases. It displays `hello &amp;quot;mister sir&amp;quot; i am quotes` in alert and `hello &quot;mister sir&quot; i am quotes` in html content

   ```
   test("@HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(lol)");
   test("@HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(lol)");
   ```
3. default c# or JavaScriptStringEncode. They do not work in alerts. It displays `hello &quot;mister sir&quot; i am quotes` in alerts.

   ```
   test("@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(lol)");
   test("@lol");
   test("@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(lol)");
   ```
4. Html.Raw(). Not works at all. It breaks mark-up with unescaped double quotes.

   ```
   test("@Html.Raw(lol)");
   ```

Can you help me with some approach which will work as javascript variant (1)?

Comment: javascript knows NOTHING of html, even though that's generally always where it's embedded. you have to produce VALID javascript representations of your string, and the easies way to do that is by encoding it into `json`.

Comment: For your _String literal_ you are escaping the double quotes, however there are no backslashs in the _String_ `lol`, so none of the characters in `lol` are escaped. A literal with escaped characters inside it would look like this `"hello \\\"mister sir\\\" I am quotes""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically it's best to use your favorite JSON serializer to encode any value that you want to inject into javascript. That will automatically add double-quotes around the string, and escape anything inside the string appropriately:

```
test(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.Serialize(lol)));
```

Comment: yeap, it's work. This solution is not beautiful, but at least it's work. Thank you